# Format my JSON string into an <ol> ordered list in PHP

Tags: php, html, json

I'm working on a simple CMS for a pet project. I currently have a JSON string that contains a list of page ID's and Parent page ID's for a menu structure.

I want to now convert this string into a nested or hierarchical list (ordered list).

I've tried looking looping through but seem to have ended up with an overly complex range of sub classes. I'm struggling to find a suitable light-weight solution in PHP.

Here's the JSON:

```
**[{"id":3,"children":[{"id":4,"children":[{"id":5}]}]},{"id":6},{"id":2},{"id":4}]**
```

Here's the desired output:

```
<ol>
  <li>3
    <ol>
      <li>4</li>
         <ol>
            <li>5</li>
         </ol>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ol>
```

Is there anything built in to PHP that can simplify this process? Has anyone had any experience of this before?

I'm a newbie to PHP and SE. Looking forward to hearing from you.

**Here's my current progress (it's not working too well)**

```
<ol>
<?php
$json = '[{"id":3,"children":[{"id":4,"children":[{"id":5}]}]},{"id":6},{"id":2},{"id":4}]';
$decoded = json_decode($json);
$pages = $decoded;
foreach($pages as $page){
   $subpages = $decoded->children;
      echo "<li>".$page->id."</li>";
    foreach($subpages as $subpage){
        echo "<li>".$subpage->id."</li>";
   }
}
?>
</ol>
```

Comment: You can accomplish this with a couple built-in PHP goodies.  For starters, use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert your JSON string to a PHP array.  After that then you can loop through it with a [foreach loop](http://at2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), or in your case, a nested `foreach`.

Comment: @DanielA.White sure - i've been on this all morning. I'll add some of what i've tried so far.

Comment: @Crackertastic thanks for the pointers - I updated my question with a snippet from my current progress. I was hacking it about so the nested <op> tag code is missing.

Comment: @ABOO You are welcome for the pointers.  I posted an answer, but I see that you have already selected one.  At any rate, glad you were able to get the help you needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use recursion to get deep inside the data. If the current value is an array then recursion again. Consider this example:

```
$json_string = '[{"id":3,"children":[{"id":4,"children":[{"id":5}]}]},{"id":6},{"id":2},{"id":4}]';
$array = json_decode($json_string, true);

function build_list($array) {
    $list = '<ol>';
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $key => $index) {
            if(is_array($index)) {
                $list .= build_list($index);
            } else {
                $list .= "<li>$index</li>";
            }
        }
    }

    $list .= '</ol>';
    return $list;
}

echo build_list($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called recursion, which can be done by a function calling itself.

If you solved once to list all nodes of the list in one function, you can then apply the same function for all child-lists. As then those child-lists will do the same on their children, too.

```
call_user_func(function ($array, $id = 'id', $list = 'children') {
    $ul = function ($array) use (&$ul, $id, $list) {
        echo '<ul>', !array_map(function ($child) use ($ul, $id, $list) {
            echo '<li>', $child[$id], isset($child[$list]) && $ul($child[$list])
                  , '</li>';
        }, $array), '</ul>';
    };
    $ul($array);
}, json_decode('[{"id":3,"children":[{"id":4,"children":[{"id":5}]}]},{"id":6},
                {"id":2},{"id":4}]', TRUE));
```

As this example shows, the `$ul` function is called recursively over the list and all children. There are other solutions, but most often recursion is a simple method here to get the job done once you've wrapped your head around it.

Demo: https://eval.in/153471 ; Output (beautified):

```
<ul>
  <li>3
    <ul>
      <li>4
        <ul>
          <li>5</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: man, this is like rocket science code! i gotta be honest this is the correct answer and should be accepted. +1

Comment: no, the accepted answer also has recursion in the code. However it perhaps doesn't explain it well. While my code isn't that easily to read than the accepted example probably.

Answer (score 2):

Using a function that can recursively go through your JSON, you can get the functionality you wish.  Consider the following code: (this only accounts for an attribute of `id` as getting listed, as your desired code shows)

```
$json = '[{"id":3,"children":[{"id":4,"children":[{"id":5}]}]},{"id":6},{"id":2},{"id":4}]';

function createOLList($group) {
    $output = (is_array($group)) ? "<ol>" : "";
    foreach($group as $attr => $item) {
        if(is_array($item) || is_object($item)) {
            $output .= createOLList($item);
        } else {
            if($attr == "id") {
                $output .= "<li>$item</li>";
            }
        }
    }
    $output .= (is_array($group)) ? "</ol>" : "";
    return $output;
}

print(createOLList(json_decode($json)));
```

This will produce the following HTML output.

```
<ol>
    <li>3</li>
    <ol>
        <li>4</li>
        <ol>
            <li>5</li>
        </ol>
    </ol>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$json_array = array();

array_push($json_array, array(
    'id' => 3,
    'children' => array(
        'id'        =>  4,
        'children'  =>  array(
                'id'    =>  5,
            )
        )
));

array_push($json_array, array('id' => 6));
array_push($json_array, array('id' => 2));
array_push($json_array, array('id' => 4));

//your json object
$json_object = json_encode($json_array);
//echo $json_object;

//here is where you decode your json object
$json_object_decoded = json_decode($json_object,true);

//for debug to see how your decoded json object looks as an array
/*
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json_object_decoded);
echo "</pre>";
*/

echo "<ol>";
foreach($json_object_decoded as $node){
    if(isset($node['id'])){
        echo "<li>" . $node['id'];
        if(isset($node['children'])){
                echo "<ol>";
                    echo "<li>" . $node['children']['id'] . "</li>";
            if(isset($node['children'])){
                echo "<ol>";
                    echo "<li>" . $node['children']['children']['id'] . "</li>";
                echo "</ol>";
            }
            echo "</ol>";
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ol>";


?>
```

Comment: this is great - however, it seems to only permit one child level. I need it to go to at least 4. Short of hacking your code and adding more loops i'm unsure how I can use it.

Comment: ok, i will edit to permit two child level, but i think the rest you can handle by yourself :). It can be done in multiple ways, you can even create a recursive function which will echo an <ol> with an corespondin <li> when a node is having a children

Answer (score 0):

I have found that i have to fix or simplify almost every of the functions above.
So here i came with something simple and working, still recursion.

```
function build_list($array) {
    $list = '<ul>';
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $list .= "<strong>$key</strong>: " . build_list($value);
        } else {
            $list .= "<li><strong>$key</strong>: $value</li>";
        }
    }
    $list .= '</ul>';
    return $list;
} 
build_list(json_encode($json_string),true);
```