# Covert Array into ul li list

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, html-lists

So I have a file that has strings of file paths that look like this..

`./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/6004_90_04 LargeHeadlightSm.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/AirHissPressureRe HIT032001.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/Impact_Metal_Bullet_Hit(1).wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/Impact_Metal_Bullet_Hit.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/6004_94_02 LargeHeavyGlassS.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/Impact_Glass_Smash.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/AirReleaseHeavyAi HIT030701.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/SDR02_15SCIF RhythmicRever.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/VAL02_08CRSH GlassBreaking.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/AirReleaseLargeAi HIT030601.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/SDR02_14SCIF Rhythmic3Beat.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/6004_94_01 LargeGlassSmash.wav`

I want to split all of these to an ul li list.so

```
> CatDV
    > S1
        > SFX
            > steam
                > filename.extension
```

And so forth...

This is the array that i'm working with. And i got this to output with the function below.

```
array(1) {
  [""]=>
  array(1) {
    ["CatDV"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["S1"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["SFX"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["steam"]=>
          array(12) {
            ["6004_90_04 LargeHeadlightSm.wav"]=>
                string(52) "./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/6004_90_04 LargeHeadlightSm.wav"
            ["AirHissPressureRe HIT032001.wav"]=>
                string(52) "./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/AirHissPressureRe HIT032001.wav"
            ["Impact_Metal_Bullet_Hit(1).wav"]=>
                string(51) "./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/Impact_Metal_Bullet_Hit(1).wav"
            ["Impact_Metal_Bullet_Hit.wav"]=>
                string(48) "./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/Impact_Metal_Bullet_Hit.wav"
            ["6004_94_02 LargeHeavyGlassS.wav"]=>
               string(52) "./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/6004_94_02 LargeHeavyGlassS.wav"
            ["Impact_Glass_Smash.wav"]=>
               string(43) "./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/Impact_Glass_Smash.wav"
            ["AirReleaseHeavyAi HIT030701.wav"]=>
               string(52) "./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/AirReleaseHeavyAi HIT030701.wav"
            ["SDR02_15SCIF RhythmicRever.wav"]=>
               string(51) "./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/SDR02_15SCIF RhythmicRever.wav"
            ["VAL02_08CRSH GlassBreaking.wav"]=>
               string(51) "./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/VAL02_08CRSH GlassBreaking.wav"
            ["AirReleaseLargeAi HIT030601.wav"]=>
              string(52) "./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/AirReleaseLargeAi HIT030601.wav"
            ["SDR02_14SCIF Rhythmic3Beat.wav"]=>
              string(51) "./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/SDR02_14SCIF Rhythmic3Beat.wav"
            ["6004_94_01 LargeGlassSmash.wav"]=>
              string(51) "./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/6004_94_01 LargeGlassSmash.wav"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now what I'm getting stuck in converting this into an ul li list that i can output into my html and style it.

```
function arch_list($output) {
// //Conditional for Archives Page
    $data = file(get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/angular/data/list_test.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    $path = array('data' => $data);
    $output = array();
    foreach ($path['data'] as $d) {
        $out = preg_split('/(\.)*\//', $d);
        $outArr = $d;
        for ($i = count($out) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {             
            $outArr = array($out[$i] => $outArr);               
        }
        // return $outArr;
        $output = array_merge_recursive($output, $outArr);

    }
    return $output;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: You can traverse your array using nested `foreach()`s, where you wrap each `foreach()` with `<ul></ul>` and inside the `foreach()` wrap each value with `<li></li>`. You could also write it as a recursive function that will do it n-levels deep in case your structure changes / is dynamic.

Comment: So you want each item that is a sub-directory to be a sub item in the list of the item that comes prior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have refactored the god-awful code in @hakre's answer to be slightly less god-aweful. It's using the same aglorithm:

```
$file = './CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/6004_90_04 LargeHeadlightSm.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/AirHissPressureRe HIT032001.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/Impact_Metal_Bullet_Hit(1).wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/Impact_Metal_Bullet_Hit.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/6004_94_02 LargeHeavyGlassS.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/Impact_Glass_Smash.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/AirReleaseHeavyAi HIT030701.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/SDR02_15SCIF RhythmicRever.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/VAL02_08CRSH GlassBreaking.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/AirReleaseLargeAi HIT030601.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/SDR02_14SCIF Rhythmic3Beat.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/6004_94_01 LargeGlassSmash.wav';
```

These are internal functions, which you don't need to directly call.

```
function splitIntoPaths($string) {
    $paths = array();
    foreach (explode("\n", $string) as $line) {
        $node = &$paths;
        foreach (explode("/", $line) as $segment) {
            if (!isset($node[$segment])) {
                $node[$segment] = array();
            }
            $node = &$node[$segment];
        }
        $node = $line;
    }
    return $paths;
}

function createListFromArray(array $array) {
    $return = "<ul>";
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $return .= "<li>" . $key;
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $return .= createListFromArray($value);
        }
        $return .= "</li>";
    }
    return $return . "</ul>";
}
```

This is the function that does the work for you, returning you a string.

```
function createTree($string) {
    $paths = splitIntoPaths($string);
    return createListFromArray($paths);
}
```

Usage:

```
$tree = createTree($file);
```

Comment: +1 for that the code is easier to read. I think a very good answer would show that by making `createListFromArray` for no children first, and then introducing the recursion.

Answer (score 3):

As you don't know the depth of your tree, you can make use of recursive function calls to display the ul/li tree. This actually works like in [this yesterdays question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740619/367456), however, you have different decision points here:

```
$file = './CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/6004_90_04 LargeHeadlightSm.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/AirHissPressureRe HIT032001.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/Impact_Metal_Bullet_Hit(1).wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/Impact_Metal_Bullet_Hit.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/6004_94_02 LargeHeavyGlassS.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/Impact_Glass_Smash.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/AirReleaseHeavyAi HIT030701.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/SDR02_15SCIF RhythmicRever.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/VAL02_08CRSH GlassBreaking.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/AirReleaseLargeAi HIT030601.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/SDR02_14SCIF Rhythmic3Beat.wav
./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/6004_94_01 LargeGlassSmash.wav';

$tree = [];
foreach (explode("\n", $file) as $line) {
    $node = &$tree;
    foreach (explode('/', $line) as $segment) {
        $node = &$node[$segment];
    }
    $node = $line;
    unset($node);
}

call_user_func(function ($array) {
    $ul = function ($array) use (&$ul) {
        echo '<ul>', !array_walk($array, function ($child, $key) use ($ul) {
            echo '<li>', $key, is_array($child) ? $ul($child) : ''
            , '</li>';
        }, $array), '</ul>';
    };
    $ul($array);
}, $tree);
```

Take note that this self-containing example code ([Demo](https://eval.in/154318)) also contains a different way to build the `$tree` array comparable but a little different to your way (the main difference is that I didn't use `array_merge_recursive()` but instead merged on my own by using references while traversing the `$tree` array).

For the recursion it's really straight forward once you've understood how recursive function calls work: Solve the problem for one list and wrap the solution into a function. Then insert a new list if that lists entries have children. Use the same function for that.

Output (beautified):

```
<ul>
    <li>.
        <ul>
            <li>CatDV
                <ul>
                    <li>S1
                        <ul>
                            <li>SFX
                                <ul>
                                    <li>steam
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>6004_90_04 LargeHeadlightSm.wav</li>
                                            <li>AirHissPressureRe HIT032001.wav</li>
                                            <li>Impact_Metal_Bullet_Hit(1).wav</li>
                                            <li>Impact_Metal_Bullet_Hit.wav</li>
                                            <li>6004_94_02 LargeHeavyGlassS.wav</li>
                                            <li>Impact_Glass_Smash.wav</li>
                                            <li>AirReleaseHeavyAi HIT030701.wav</li>
                                            <li>SDR02_15SCIF RhythmicRever.wav</li>
                                            <li>VAL02_08CRSH GlassBreaking.wav</li>
                                            <li>AirReleaseLargeAi HIT030601.wav</li>
                                            <li>SDR02_14SCIF Rhythmic3Beat.wav</li>
                                            <li>6004_94_01 LargeGlassSmash.wav</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is great! It worked right off the bat. How would you approach this if you wanted to save the output into a variable? The output of that variable is just a ul li string so '<ul><li>CatDV<ul><li>...' and so forth? I'm going to award you the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Instead of `echo` concatenate a `$buffer` variable, then `return` it. Initialize the `$buffer` at the very beginning to an empty string.

Comment: This is not JavaScript. You don't need to (and shouldn't) be using immediately-executing anonymous functions. Additionally, **please** don't rely on order-of-execution of comma separated echo variables like that. That's simply abuse. Separate out the code so it's readable.

Comment: @ircmaxell: Just for reference, not that I hadn't hat answered it w/o closures earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8021033/367456

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $fileToOpen="/js/angular/data/list_test.txt";

    function arch_list($fileToOpen) {
        if(file_exists($fileToOpen)){
            $file=fopen($fileToOpen,"r");
            while($line = fgets($file)){
               //We have a line of the file,split it up
               $directories=explode("/",$line);
                //Remove the period, it will be the first element in the array
               $directories=array_shift($directories);
               //Add this set of directories to a parent array
               $allDirectories[]=$directories;
            }
            fclose($fileToOpen);

        }//End of opening file

        //We now have a multidimensional array, 
        //An array holding arrays with each set of directories.
        if(!empty($allDirectories)){
           foreach($allDirectories as $directory){
               $fullString.="<ul class='your-class'>";
               foreach($directory as $pathway){
                   //We have each single item in a directory path
                     $fullString.="<li>".$pathway."</li>";
               }
               $fullString.="</ul>";
           }
        }
        return $fullString;
    }

    echo arch_list($fileToOpen);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at @hakre 's. It puts the lowest level key=>value as 2 <li>'s which I don't think is what is wanted.  My solution (given that one has the multi-dimensional array):

```
$arrayvar = array("blank?"=>
  array("CatDV"=>
    array("S1"=>
      array("SFX"=>
        array("steam"=>
          array("6004_90_04 LargeHeadlightSm.wav"=>
            "./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/6004_90_04 LargeHeadlightSm.wav", 
                "AirHissPressureRe HIT032001.wav"=>
            "./CatDV/S1/SFX/steam/AirHissPressureRe HIT032001.wav"))))));
makeul($arrayvar);            

function makeul($avar) { // make ul
  if (!is_array($avar)) exit("Err: not an array");
  echo("<ul>");
  reset($avar); while(true) { // loop through array
    $key = key($avar);     
    if (is_null($key)) break; // if NULL, end of loop
    $val = $avar[$key];
    if (is_scalar($val)) zecho("<li>$key=>$val</li> ");
    else { zecho("<li>$key"); makeul($val); zecho("</li>"); } // recurse
    next($avar); } 
  zecho("</ul>");
  }
function zecho($param) { // echo with br & \n
  echo $param, "<br />\n"; 
  }
```

Edit (for hakre): I learned a lot from your code, thank you, but isn't it unnecessarily obscure?
Wouldn't the following be as good and more clear?

```
$tree = ..
makeul($tree, '');

function makeul($val, $key) { 
  if ($key <> "") echo "<li>$key\n";
  if (is_array($val)) { 
    echo("<ul>"); array_walk($val, 'makeul'); echo("</ul>\n"); }
  else {
    echo("=>$val<br />\n"); }
  if ($key <> "") echo "</li>";
  }
```

Comment: Instead of that `exit` just prefix the parameter with `array` so that the type is hinted: `function makeul(array $avar)` - that's easier to write and helpful in many more directions than the exit. Just a comment. And for stripping away the `.` level, it's actually much easier: use `$tree['.']` - https://eval.in/private/775065a6b1e258

Comment: @hakre - I appreciate your comments. My edit adds a version of your routine that is, I hope, more clear.